# Sentence transformation!

Tags: syntactic-analysis

How do you write this sentence: "My family and I like to rest at the weekend."
using the word ***easy***. "My family and I ____ at the weekend."

Thanks!

Comment: What is easy then?

Comment: You might find our sister sight [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)  better for this type of question.

Answer (score 1):

My family and I like to ***take it easy*** at the week-end.

Answer (score 1):

My family and I like to take it easy at the weekend.

'weekend' http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/weekend#translations